# Fitting equal rectangles into larger rectangle

Tags: algorithm, geometry, rectangles

I have a single large rectangle of `dimensions L*W`, and `n smaller rectangles` that each have the same dimension `l * w`. Every small rectangle has the same `dimensions`.

My goal is to fit all `n of smaller` rectangles into the large rectangle while making the most efficient use of space in the large rectangle possible. l and w can be scaled up or down as needed, as long as the proportion is kept the same.

**How can it be determined how the smaller rectangles should be scaled to fit them all in the large rectangle?**

Comment: Do you mean scaling all small rectangles by the same factor?

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an algorithm that finds the max value of a scaling factor `F` such that all small `a x b` rectangles, when scaling by `F` will fit in the containing rectangle `A x B`:

1. For every pair `(p, q)` of positive integers such that

- `p <= n`
- `q <= n`
- `n = p * q - r` for some integer `r >= 0` satisfying `r < p` or `p < q`

compute `f = min(A/(a*p), B/(b*q)).`
2. Let `F` be the maximum of all factors `f` computed in 1.

The computation of all pairs `(p, q)` may proceed as follows:

1. [Initialize] `p := 0`
2. [Increment] `p := p + 1`
3. [End?] If `p > n`, stop
4. [Next] Let `q := (n + p - 1) / p` (integer division). Next pair `(p, q)`.
5. [Repeat] Go to 2.

**Idea of the algorithm**

Every pair `(p, q)` represents a particular layout of the scaled rectangles with `p` rectangles in an horizontal row and `q` rows, the last one possibly incomplete. Here is an example for `n = 13` written as `3 * 5 - 2`:
[image]

Since `p` scaled rectangles of width `f*a` must fit in a rectangle of width `A`, we have: `p*f*a <= A` or `f <= A/(p*a)`. Similarly `f <= B/(q*b).` Therefore the maximum scale for this configuration is `min(A/(p*a), B/(q*b)).`