# Best fitting rectangle with a variable number of small rectangles keeping aspect ratio

Tags: algorithm, math, rectangles

I need to find the optimal placement of a given N child rectangles keeping the aspect ratio of the father rectangle.
Use case is the following:
- the father rectangle is a big picture, let's say 4000x3000 pixels (this one can be rescaled).
- child rectangles are 296x128 pixels (e-ink displays of users)

The objective is to show the big picture across all the current number of displays (this number can change from 1 to 100)

This is an example:

[image]

Can happen that number of small rectangles will not fit the big rectangle aspect ratio, like if number of small rectangles is odd, in this case I can think to have like a small number (max 5) of spare rectangles to add in order to complete the big rectangle.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more mathematically and explain the constraints? For example the displays must be placed in the same direction (like in the example or some can be vertical, too)? And I imagine that the rescaling must maintain the ratio (for example I can't rescale 3000x4000 to 2000x1000) right?

Comment: All displays should be placed in same direction.
The image can be rescaled to any size but trying to keep the same aspect ratio.
Is it possible to add some padding around the image but the image should be shown across all displays.

Comment: Maybe this can give you some inspiration, is a quite similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687820/fitting-equal-rectangles-into-larger-rectangle

Answer (score 1):

this seems to be a valid approach (python + opencv)

```
import cv2
import imutils

def split_image(image, boards_no=25, boards_shape=(128, 296), additional=5):

    # find image aspect ratio
    aspect_ratio = image.shape[1]/image.shape[0]
    print("\nIMAGE INFO:", image.shape, aspect_ratio)

    # find all valid combination of a,b that maximize your available badges
    valid_props = [(a, b) for a in range(boards_no+additional+1) for b in range(boards_no+additional+1) if a*b in [q for q in range(boards_no, boards_no+additional)]]
    print("\nVALID COMBINATIONS", valid_props)

    # find all aspect ratio from previous combination
    aspect_ratio_all = [
        {
            'board_x': a, 
            'board_y': b, 
            'aspect_ratio': (a*boards_shape[1])/(b*boards_shape[0]), 
            'shape': (b*boards_shape[0], a*boards_shape[1]),
            'type': 'h'
        } for (a, b) in valid_props]
    aspect_ratio_all += [
        {
            'board_x': a, 
            'board_y': b, 
            'aspect_ratio': (a*boards_shape[0])/(b*boards_shape[1]), 
            'shape': (b*boards_shape[1], a*boards_shape[0]),
            'type': 'v'
        } for (a, b) in valid_props]

    min_ratio_diff = min([abs(aspect_ratio-x['aspect_ratio']) for x in aspect_ratio_all])
    best_ratio = [x for x in aspect_ratio_all if abs(aspect_ratio-x['aspect_ratio']) == min_ratio_diff][0]
    print("\MOST SIMILAR ASPECT RATIO:", best_ratio)

    # resize image maximining height or width
    resized_img = imutils.resize(image, height=best_ratio['shape'][0])
    border_width = int((best_ratio['shape'][1] - resized_img.shape[1]) / 2)
    border_height = 0

    if resized_img.shape[1] > best_ratio['shape'][1]:
        resized_img = imutils.resize(image, width=best_ratio['shape'][1])
        border_height = int((best_ratio['shape'][0] - resized_img.shape[0]) / 2)
        border_width = 0
    print("RESIZED SHAPE:", resized_img.shape, "BORDERS (H, W):", (border_height, border_width))

    # fill the border with black
    resized_img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(
        resized_img,
        top=border_height,
        bottom=border_height,
        left=border_width,
        right=border_width,
        borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,
        value=[0, 0, 0]
    )

    # split in tiles
    M = resized_img.shape[0] // best_ratio['board_y']
    N = resized_img.shape[1] // best_ratio['board_x']
    return [resized_img[x:x+M,y:y+N] for x in range(0,resized_img.shape[0],M) for y in range(0,resized_img.shape[1],N)]

image = cv2.imread('image.jpeg')
tiles = split_image(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

Our solutions will always be rectangles into which we have fit the biggest picture that we can keeping the aspect ratio correct.  The question is how we grow them.

In your example a single display is `296 x 128`.  (Which I assume is length and height.)  Our scaled image to 1 display is `170.6 x 128`.  (You can take out fractional pixels in your scaling.)

The rule is that at all points, whatever direction is filled gets filled in with more displays so we can expand the picture.  In the single display solution we therefore go from a `1x1` rectangle to a `1x2` one and we now have `296 x 256`.  Our scaled image is now `296 x 222`.

Our next solution will be a `2x2` display.  This gives us `594 x 256` and our scaled image is `321.3 x 256`.

Next we get a `2x3` display.  This gives us `594 x 384` and our scaled display is now `512 x 384`.

Since we are still maxing on the second dimension we next go to `2x4`.  This gives us `594 x 512` and our scaled display is `594 x 445.5`.  And so on.

For your problem it will not take long to run through all of the sizes up to however many displays you have, and you just take the biggest rectangle that you can make from the list.

Important special case.  If the display rectangle and image have the same aspect ratio, you have to add to both dimensions.  Which in the case that the image and the displays have the same aspect ratio gives you `1 x 1`, `2 x 2`, `3 x 3` and so on through the squares.